# How to alert leave Stite "Changes you made may not be saved." alert

Tags: javascript, alert

I have this website (I'm almost positive you can only do this with web applications but I wanted to check) Is it possible to do this with [javascript](/questions/tagged/javascript)?

Is there something else we can add into an `alert()` to show buttons that we'll either close or keep the tab?

```
function closeTab(){
   alert('Changes you made may not be saved.');
   //add buttons here
}
```

[image: Image of Alert]

**Alert:**

Leave Site:

Changes you made may not be saved.

Answer (score 0):

You can use confirm dialog:

```js
confirm("Really?");               // yes/no dialog, returns true/false depending on user click
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use confirm which is similar to alert but has two options for the user to choose from. It returns true if they confirm and false otherwise so you can close the Tab or just do nothing depending on what they choose.

```
function closeTab(){
   if (confirm('Changes you made may not be saved.')) {
   //Do the code for closing the tab
   }
}
```